OST files of Exchange mailbox expands way over mailboxes sizes
I have an exciting phenomenon here with an Exchange mailbox created on different Windows 10 computers in Outlook 2019, which might be fun for experts to track down the cause of.
Below is the setting, then the observed phenomenon:
An Exchange mailbox was added to Outlook, which is also created in an Outlook profile on another computer.
The Exchange cache was activated in both profiles and "All" was specified as the time period.
The mailbox has x GB on the server, about 20 GB more than Outlook allows.
For this reason, the adjustable threshold value for the data file was raised some time ago using the MaxLargeFileSize and WarnLargeFileSize keys.
The mailbox grew to the aforementioned 70 GB.
The mailbox copy created in Exchange cache mode in the first profile created also grew to the same value.
Outlook knows about the real size of the mailbox: local and server size of the outlook data file doesn't differ remarbably.
In the separately created Outlook profile, the size of the OST expands to 112 GB in the meantime.
The Outlook OST file can be shrunk to the expected size by means of repair. The expansion then starts again.
Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?
Outlook profile has been deleted. Doesn't change behaviour.
Best regards
Springfeld
